# Matlab Warnings with "xlswrite" and "xlsread"

Tags: excel, matlab, warnings, office-2013

Hi I have 64 bit Matlab 2017b and 64 bit 2013 Office installed on my computer (Windows 7), and I am trying to run a Matlab script which reads and write .xlsx files. However every time the functions 'xlsread' and 'xlswrite' are called I get the following errors respectively:

'Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used. Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information. '

and..

'Warning: Could not start Excel server for export. XLSWRITE will attempt to write file in CSV format.'

I have tried many suggestions from other people with similar issues, but yet to get this problem resolved.  Does anybody have some ideas what could be causing this?  Many thanks in advance.